# where to find goldman sachs ratings of stocks?

Tags: stocks

Quoting http://www.moneyflowindex.org/shares-of-principal-financial-group-inc-nysepfg-sees-large-outflow-of-money-3/3128858/,

> Goldman Sachs downgrades their rating on the shares of Principal Financial Group Inc (NYSE:PFG). The current rating of the shares is Sell. Earlier, the shares were rated a Neutral by the brokerage firm.

How can I see what Goldman Sachs has rated stocks?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [their site](http://www.goldmansachs.com/research/equity_ratings.html)? Some places may have portions available though also beware that some companies may charge for some of their research pieces.

Comment: Yes. It seems to me that for NYSE:PFG that the only place where they provide a rating is in the graph where it says "May 15, 2015 to N from CS". But if the current rating is N then that means Neutral - not Sellso it doesn't seem like that's current. And I tried it for another stock ticker - NYSE:RATE - and didn't see anything in even the graph, be it out of date or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one the links for Goldmansachs. Not to state the obvious, but most of their research is only available to their clients.

http://www.goldmansachs.com/research/equity_ratings.html